# Expected value or median of a function defined on sphere with uniform distribution

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, expectation, concentration-of-measure

Suppose $S$ is the sphere of radius one. And suppose $f:S\to \mathbb{R}$ is defined as follows:
$$f(x_1,...,x_n)=\frac{1}{x_1^2}+\frac{1}{x_2^2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{x_n^2}$$

I am trying to calculate either of these:
$$\int f(\gamma)d\gamma$$ where integrating is with respect to Haar measure over the sphere. Or maybe finding the median of the induced random variable on $\mathbb{R}$ by $f$. I appreciate any help in this direction.

Comment: Each integral $$\int_S\frac1{x_k^2}d\gamma(x)$$ is infinite, no?

Comment: Why is that? Actually $S$ is compact and therefore $f$ has a maximum over it and therefore the integral should also be bounded, right?

Comment: The existence of the maximum is not guaranteed since the function is defined on D which is not the whole set S. Furthermore, the supremum of the function over the intersection of D and S is...

Comment: I assume $D$ is the set where $f$ is defined over it, right? I made a mistake and I think I understand your point. Thank you!

Comment: Why "assume", just read: `the function is defined on D`.

Comment: Where I didn't know what $D$ is referring to! :D You just suddenly wrote $D$...

Comment: @Did but now that I think about it isn't the case that $S\setminus D$ is of measure zero?! Can you elaborate why each integral of type $\int_S \frac{1}{x_k^2}d\gamma$ is infinite?

Comment: Seriously? Surely you can try to reach this conclusion on your own...

Comment: Yes seriously. My calculus is quite bad. At least I appreciate a direction.... beside this is not a homework, as one can appreciate my walking in the darkness

Comment: Hint: Show that the integral *on the real line* $$\int_\mathbb R\frac1{x^2}dx$$ diverges, then determine what is different and what is not with the integral $$\int_S\frac1{x_1^2}dx.$$

Comment: @Did, May I ask if the following proof make sense? 
The first integral you suggested has the closed formula as $\frac{-1}{x}$ for any interval $[c,1)$ or $(-1,-c]$ where $c<1$ (it is bounded for any x>1 anyway). But it diverges the more $c$ gets close to zero! 

for the main integral I considered only the second dimension and did a change of variable for $x_1=\cos(\theta)$ and then the integral can be caluclated as $\frac{1}{\cos(\theta)}$ in closed form. Then the reasoning for the first integral holds again! Is it right?

Comment: The argument for the 1D integral is oddly phrased and the extension to every dimension is incomplete but this is the idea, yes.